# Resample error in pandas: resampled df not appearing

Tags: pandas, resample

I want to resample a df from daily measurements to yearly measurements.

I have set a DateTime as the index and tried to resample, but the av_df_130302A df doens't appear in my Variable exploreer and nothing happens.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

`df_130302A = df_130302A.set_index('DateTime')                                                    av_df_130302A = df_130302A.resample('Y').sum`

[image: This is a picture of the console when I run the code enter image description here]

Comment: With no error message and no code that we can test its hard for anyone to help.  Can you prepare a small reproducible example of the problem with a small set of data?

Comment: Having said that, it looks like you forgot the parenthesis on your sum method.  It should be `.sum()`

Comment: And that was literally my problem - that's hilarious! Thanks so much, I should have noticed that :)

Comment: Something as trivial as that probably isn't worth having a question for.  You may want to delete it.